# How do I get a search Image into my Sheet from column text with ImportXML?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with a thousand items in a column and I want another column to its right which gives me the first image you get when you search the text term in Google Images. Is there any way to do this with ImportXML for specifically Google Images search?

Answer (score 3):

**Return Images from Google Search based on Cell Value**

with this you need only change the cell value as though it were a search bar, outcome:

[google sheets outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ9b9.png)

where changes to cells in column C alter the image results in F

I don't know how @Gabriel Carballo's formula works entirely with `QUERY` and `IMPORTXML` but this is how I managed to modify it to work for me.

Using @Gabriel Caballo 's answer, you can search/return images based on the cell value, by instead of pointing to a static URL in D1, utilise CONCATENATE to construct the format for searching on Google Images:

```
=INDEX(IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(D1, "//a//@src"),"where Col1 contains 'image' limit 2")))
```

where D1 is the cell containing,

```
= CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/search?q=", substitute(C1," ", "+"), "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_sfHlpeb8AhUvhP0HHVD6B6oQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=1009&dpr=1")
```

the `CONCATENATE` to create make the URL

https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtmoeks_v2AhXlTDABHTUsCvgQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1920&bih=929&dpr=1

where in this example, as in Gabriel's, is `dogs`

and the strings to `CONCATENATE` are:

1. "https://www.google.com/search?q="
2. substitute(C1, " ", "+")
3. "source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_sfHlpeb8AhUvhP0HHVD6B6oQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=1009&dpr=1"

String 2 inserts the search term into the URL, but as the URL does not accept " " (spaces) and instead '+' are used, string 2 substitutes them.

Where C1 is the cell with the item you are searching for such as:

- `dog`
- `cat`
- dog and cat

for something like 'dog and cat', string 2 (substitute) turns that into 'dog+and+'cat'

This will display the image in the cell below the cell containing your index image formula, so if you are using a list with rows from which you would like to generate the images, utilise TRANSPOSE:

```
=Transpose(INDEX(IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(D1, "//a//@src"),"where Col1 contains 'image' limit 2"))))
```

which will display the image in the cell to the right instead.

The image will adjust to the cell size, rather than adjust the cell to the image, so in order to have all your images visible, I recommend increasing all your cells in bulk by selecting the cell rows and right clicking which will show a drop down menu with "resize rows" allowing you to simultaneously change all the sizes of the selected rows. Or alter the `mode` argument of `IMAGE`.

Additionally:

The reason the image is shifted one space over than where the cell containing the formula is, is because the first "image" returned is blank from Google Images, which is likely why Gabriel has "limit 2" in the 'QUERY' - as to include the second image that actually contains the result. (Increasing this limit will allow you to return more image results)

To shift this back into the cell you can alter the 'row' argument of 'index' to 2:

```
=transpose(index(IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(D1, "//a//@src"),"where Col1 contains 'image' limit 2")), 2))
```

which grabs the second image. Using this in combination with the 'limit' from inside 'QUERY' will allow you to select specific images as well.

This is not limited to Google Images, the `CONCATENATE` formula for other website that use a similar search format in the URL; or webpages; or replace the whole formula with the URL you would like to grab images from.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to scrap an image from Google Search however I haven't found a way to perform a Google search based on a specific word from Google sheets as you are requesting, however you can try this:

1. Perform a Google search of the word you are trying to get an image for.
2. In Google Sheets paste the URL in a cell of the google search that you have performed.
3. Use the following formula to get the first image:

   =INDEX(IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(D1, "//a//@src"),"where Col1 contains 'image' limit 2")))

In my example I was using cell D1 to get the URL and I performed the search using the word `Dog`.

4. This is the Outcome:
   [image]

Analyzing what you are trying to do may not be ideal for performing a search for each word independently but you can at least scrap the image of the first result when searching for a specific word.

This is the URL used in my example: https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtmoeks_v2AhXlTDABHTUsCvgQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1920&bih=929&dpr=1

Comment: That works awesome!.. but how to get the image to be placed in the same cell as formula??... I'm getting the image (as you show in the screenshot) in the cell below (why!? how to change it?) Thanks in advance!